# According to Pastafarian myth, which day of the week is for pasta?

Tags: calendar-dates, pastafarianism

I always eat noodles on Friday, as do adherents of the Church of the Flying Spaghetti Monster; see [this excerpt](http://spaghettimonster.com/church-of-the-flying-spaghetti-monster-founded/the-gospel-of-the-flying-spaghetti-monster/) from [*The Gospel of the Flying Spaghetti Monster* (Henderson 2006)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gospel_of_the_Flying_Spaghetti_Monster) for explanation of the significance of Friday. Some folks, like Imgur user "IDontCareAtAllButIShould", eat pasta on Wednesday; see [`fsm wednesday` tagged galleries on Imgur](https://imgur.com/t/fsm_wednesday) for dozens of their Wednesday posts. **What myths support these traditions?** More specifically, **why do some people prefer Wednesday for pasta, while others prefer Friday for noodles?**

Comment: Obviously, Friday is easy to explain by appeal to the *Gospel*; however, I genuinely don't know where Wednesday came from.

Answer (score 1):

It's an [advertising slogan](https://dagostinopasta.com/blogs/all-about-pasta/why-wednesday-is-spaghetti-day).

> Most days, Anthony takes his time going home, But not today. Today is Wednesday, and as every family in the North End of Boston will tell you, Wednesday is Prince Spaghetti Day.